# Two lines in h1 tag

Tags: html, css

I need to fit two lines in one h1 tag (instead of making two separated h1 tags).

How can I create a line break inside of h1 tag?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Using:

```
<h1>Line 1 <br/> Line 2</h1>
```

Comment: See JWorks Studios answer below for valid html way to accomplish this.

Comment: Pretty sure this is valid - at least in HTML 5!

Answer (score 37):

A [W3C validated](https://validator.w3.org/) method is

```
<h1>Line 1 <span style = "display: block;">Line 2</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 23):

Summarizing all clever answers, this is what https://validator.w3.org says for each one:

## Validated:

```html
<h1>Line 1 <br/> Line 2</h1>
<h1>Line 1<br>Line 2</h1>
<h1>Line 1 <span style = "display: block;">Line 2</span></h1>
```

## Invalid

```html
<h1>
    <p>Line1</p>
    <p>Line2</p>
</h1>
```

Reason:

> Error: Element p not allowed as child of element h1 in this context

---

```html
<h1>
  <div>line1</div>
  <div>line2</div>
</h1>
```

Reason:

> Error: Element div not allowed as child of element h1 in this context.

---

### Tested code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Line 1 <br/> Line 2</h1>
<h1>Line 1<br>Line 2</h1>
<h1>
    <p>Line1</p>
    <p>Line2</p>
</h1>
<h1>Line 1 <span style = "display: block;">Line 2</span></h1>

<h1>
  <div>line1</div>
  <div>line2</div>
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can you make sure that line2 has a different font size?

Comment: Enclose it with a span that changes the font size.

Answer (score 10):

You can insert markup inside `h1`, so that you can simply do `<h1>foo<br>bar</h1>`.

Answer (score 6):

**Standard quote that `br` inside `h1` is valid**

Let's teach more people to read the current standard

[4.3.6 "The h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, and h6 elements"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements) says:

> Content model: Phrasing content.

Then we click the definition of "Phrasing content", which leads to [3.2.5.2.5 "Phrasing content"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2) which says:

> Phrasing content is the text of the document, as well as elements that mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level. Runs of phrasing content form paragraphs.
>
> ..., br, ..., span, ...

so we see that `br` is in the huge list of phrasing content elements, and therefore can go inside `h1`.

This also shows us that another option would be to do something like:

```
<h1><span>ab</span><span>cd</span></h1>
```

and then make the `span` be `display: inline-block;` with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use the line break tag**

```
<h1>heading1 <br> heading2</h1>
```

**You can also do it with PHP**

```
$str = "heading1 heading2 heading3";
$h1 = '<h1>';
foreach(explode(" ",$str) as $data)
{
 $h1 .= $data .'<br>';
}
$h1 .= '</h1>';

echo $h1;
```

Comment: the php part creates 3 h1 and 3 br tags

Comment: fixed the above issue after your last edit