# How to display <h1> element vertically (every character on a new line)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `h1` element that looks something like this:
[image]

But I want the output to look something like this:

[image]

Is there a way that we can achieve it in HTML5? CSS3? JavaScript? JQuery?
Please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: You can use `word-wrap` CSS property. You set a small width and `break-word` for the `word-wrap` property. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1eje4uu4/. I can't tell you how reliable is this option, but it's one way to go.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846448/two-lines-in-h1-tag

Comment: @EricMartinez, this is what im looking for, please post this as an answer so that you will be acknowledge. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As requested by @Ethyl I'm posting this as an answer

You can use `word-wrap` CSS property. You set a small `width` and `break-word` for the `word-wrap` property. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1eje4uu4/.

**HTML**

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    width: 5px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

I can't tell you how reliable is this option, but it's one way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<BR>` inside an `<H1>`.

```html
<H1>H<BR>e<BR>l<BR>l<BR>o</H1>
```

Comment: Really? Within H1? How?

Comment: Just use <H1>H<BR>e<BR>l<BR>l<BR>o</H1>.

Comment: It work, if the textnode is static, what about if the content was retrieved to the database?

Comment: Either look into the css suggestion in another answer (I don't know whether it works), or you could just have php or a script insert <BR> inbetween every character in the title when it's retrieved from the database..

Comment: Btw, you can style parts of a title differently by using SPANs.

Comment: @EthylCasin: use jquery to `slpit` and then join, it is reliable over different screen sizes and also you don't need to change your html. Check the demo in my answer.

Comment: Simple javascript will do: "Hello".split("").join("<BR>")

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1>H<br>E<br>L<br>L<br>O</h1>
```

And the output

## H
E
L
L
O

Comment: I want it to be dynamic as much as possible. Lets say the contents was retrieved in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `jQuery`:

`$('h1').html($('h1').html().split('').join('<br>'))`

Working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/1eje4uu4/3/)

** this will work on dynamic text.Check this with dynamic [data](http://jsfiddle.net/1eje4uu4/4/)

Comment: @m69: </br> was a type, i did it everywhere sorry. I have updated the the answer now.

Comment: The guy who copied your answer, including the typo, seems to have deleted it :-)